# Python Plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, plotly-express

I have a file with lat / lon and I want to project this on a heatmap.
I'm trying to do this with a density_mapbox.  It works but I can't figure out how to let it soom in on Belgium.  I tried zoom, but it doesn't seem to work, I still get the map of the whole world.

```
full_path = fm.join_path_filename(DIR_IN, filename)
df = pd.read_excel(full_path)

fig = px.density_mapbox(df, lat='breedtegraad',
                        lon='lengtegraad',
                        radius=10,
                        title="Data",
                        hover_data=["adres", "plaats", "postcode", "land"],
                        center=dict(lat=50.93106, lon=5.33781),
                        zoom=0,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain",
                        )

fig.show()
```

Comment: If you set the zoom value to 6 or 7, I think you will see Belgium. Try:`zoom=6 or zoom=7`

Comment: It worked fine. with zoom 6.  Thanks !